# Media isn't showing in Wordpress library but is available in uploads folder

Tags: php, wordpress, ubuntu, digital-ocean

I am trying to migrate my site from shared hosting to the digital ocean.

I have uploaded wp-content and my site is over 3 years old. 
Now when I am checking into the media on the dashboard.

Files aren't showing. Ideally, all the months should be visible but as you can see in the image only selected no of months are shown. 
How can I get the Wordpress to show all the months and images? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfBT2.png)

Comment: Check file permission, if the folder path is correct, it should appear unless it has permission issue

Answer (score 0):

Let me know, if it works or not!

```
The image that is not showing for me has this location!

wp-content/uploads/2019/02/spring.png
```

[image: my image path that is not showing]

```
I have to check, Whether the permission for uploads folder, 2019 folder and then for 
02 folder are same or not
Go to your wp-content folder
```

[image]

```
Then check each folder permission they have to be the same!
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

```
In my case they are same now go to your database and delete the upload path in your 
wp-database option

Go to wp-options and look for upload path, it can be on the second page also, search 
for it
```

[image]

```
cut the path and paste it somewhere else, and make the path empty
```

[image]
[image]
    Now upload and image again to see if it is showing in media library or not.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. There are folders in the wp-content/uploads 
Like 
2017
2018
2019
2020 
but only 2017 and 2020 are visible in the media option in Wordpress 2019 and 2018 images aren't showing there.

Comment: I think you miss understood the question.